# Get values from mysql database and store in php array

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project with php and Mysql where I need to get values from Mysql database and store them into array.

Code:

```
$con=new mysqli("localhost","root","","databse");
$sql="select name from data";
$result= array();
$result=$con->query($sql);
```

How to store the data in php array?

Answer (score 3):

**Here is an example of how to do it!**

```
 //MySQLi information

    $db_host     = "localhost";
    $db_username = "username";
    $db_password = "password";

    //connect to mysqli database (Host/Username/Password)
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

    //select MySQLi dabatase table
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "table") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

   $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM data");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
   $names[] = $row['name'];
}
```

**Edit: 
Print the results out by using**

```
print_r($names);
```

or

```
foreach($names as $name) {
echo "$name";
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: It showed me an error:


Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax_admin_image\ar.php on line 10

Comment: Make sure that you have the database information correct. Anyways, from my answer, I edited  | select * from date | to | select * from data | This might be why! Make it "data"

Comment: I already changed that field. From date to data.

Comment: I succesfully sorted it. Switching $result and in the place of $row solves that problem..

Comment: Updated my code, copy everything back and change the MySQL information! Fixed the problem! Yup figured it 2 mins ago!

Comment: But, it's showing another problem :


Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax_admin_image\ar.php on line 10

Comment: re-copy my code please and change database information, everything will work fine now!

Comment: Now it's showing:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax_admin_image\ar.php on line 10

Comment: Why is it using mysql_fetch_array() since we are using mysqli unless you are not following my code!